# How does one delete a tag?

Tags: support, tags

I may be missing something obvious here, but I don't see how to delete a tag.

I'm looking to delete [this tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smelting) so it's no longer a candidate for auto-complete (thus encouraging its further use).

Answer (score 4):

There are only two ways really:

1. The hard way - remove the tag from all questions through question deletion, tag merging or just manual untagging. Once the last use of the tag has been removed, the suggestion will go away on its own.
2. The dev way - ask a dev to nuke it from orbit. (Mods can't do this.)

Comment: I did it the hard way (it had one usage) but it still shows up as an auto-complete option when I try to use it on a question. :(

Comment: @Shaun Yeah, it'll last up to 24 days, then vanish.

Comment: Before I put in a feature request: have we requested to be able to nuke it at the mod level?

Comment: @Shaun There's [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70910/is-there-a-way-to-batch-remove-a-tag) from a while back, but it's tagged support, not feature request (and unanswered, to boot). There's also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81412/155160), which suggests that it used to be possible for moderators to do this but isn't any longer.